# Building an iPhone application from the command line, without xcodebuild

Tags: iphone, scons, building

It is possible to build an iPhone application manually, without using `xcodebuild` nor an Xcode project?

The idea is to build the application using SCons without creating an Xcode project. I know there is the `codesign` command line tool, that I could use, but before I start reverse engineering the Xcode build process, I was wondering if anybody has experience with this or has done it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible to write a makefile using gcc.  You're going to want to set your GCC to use frameworks from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/ (frameworks being in system/library/frameworks, and usr/lib).

As far as specifics, I think you're going to have to work that out yourself - but pay careful consideration to the architecture options in GCC and you should have something working quickly.

Comment: I have something working so far, I will polish it and post it here when finished.

Comment: Hi Nicolas. I was wondering if you got something working yet?

Comment: making binary objects and linking them is easy, but how do you package all the resources together into a bundle, and how do you sign the resulting app?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode just wraps gcc/g++ and ld (and yes, codesign).  Take a look at any Xcode project build output and you'll see what commands it uses.  I believe the key to building an iphone app is the -arch parameter.

Comment: I did that, but there are some command that are "internal" to Xcode, like `<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> `.